# Why does the factanal() function in R limit the number of factors?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, degrees-of-freedom

When running a factor analysis using the `factanal()` function in R, if you ask for too many factors, you receive the following error (obviously, depending on the number of variables and factors in question):

```
Error in factanal(data, factors = 5, scores = "regression") : 
  5 factors are too many for 8 variables
```

In the code, this error is returned if the following code evaluates to a negative value.

```
dof <- 0.5 * ((p - factors)^2 - p - factors)
```

Obviously this is a matter of degrees of freedom of the model, but why is this the calculation for the degrees of freedom?

Comment: Consider how many parameters are needed to specify a orthogonal (that is, rotation) matrix of a given size.

Comment: @whuber The correlation matrix will provide 0.5*(p^2 - p) variables. So that should be the degrees of freedom (which I believe is the answer to your question)
But the loading on the factors should take up f*p degrees of freedom (the loading for each variable on each factor), but why are the degrees of freedom reduced by an additional factor, and why does the removal of f*p dof also multiplied by 0.5?